# where is mongoimport on ubuntu?

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, mongoimport

on my ubuntu server

[image]

Do you know where is mongoimport

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I need to install it via [official website](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#).

The one comes with ubuntu doesn't have `mongoimport`